# Facebook Authorization redirecting to "The page you requested was not found" on mobile devices

Tags: facebook

I've been building out a social gifting platform, and have had an application running for a few months now at: `http://egift.me/promos/venue/facebookconnect`

There is a simple user flow for the app. Click the Login/Connect facebook button, login &/or authorize the application, and you're redirected to a 'thank you/confirmation' style page.

If I step through this on a standard browser, I have no problems. If I step through this on mobile, I ultimately get the lovely "The page you requested was not found" page.

I don't have a Mobile Web url configured, I'm simply using Website with Facebook Login. Even when I have tried adding a mobile web url (it's the same base URL, I'm using View Switching to serve up a desktop vs mobile optimized view), I get the same issue.

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Is there any additional information I can provide?

[UPDATE]

This works (be sure to change your scope):

```
//instead of onClick could just as easily use something like jQuery event binding
<button onClick="loginUser();">Login</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loginUser() {
    FB.login(function (response) { }, { scope: 'YOUR_SCOPE_HERE' });
}

FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', handleResponse);
});
handleResponse = function (response) {
    document.body.className = response.authResponse ? 'connected' : 'not_connected';
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
        // app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
        // request, and the time the access token 
        // and signed request each expire
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to FB, but has not yet authenticated your app
    } else {
        // the user is not logged in to FB
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: This is the error you get when the mobile URL is not configured or correct. Are you sure it's in place and matches the domain of the app?

Comment: app domain: egift.me. Site URL: egift.me ... mobile site URL: egift.me (when I've had a mobile site url configured). Do the URL's need to match exactly (eg shouldn't both egift.me/promos/venue/facebookconnect &  egift.me/promos/burgerking/freewhopper work) ?? I have seen several examples of companies who have a "shared facebook app" (woobox/wildfire to name two) for different merchants, which gives them different URLs, so I have to imagine I should be able to do that...

Comment: Just to be clear, the URLs in both your fields have http:// or https:// at the start?

Mobile/desktop can be different: just make sure that both are provided in the list of owned domains (just below the contact email field)

Comment: bah, stupid SO link :) yes, they both have the http:// up front

Comment: > And the domains are in the field above? What is your app id?

App ID: 441079762589798. Screenshot showing my settings

Comment: There's something a bit odd here. Even on the desktop I never seem to properly log in (the Login button shows even when I have).

The root cause is probably that you're expecting the Login button to work on mobile. In fact it doesn't (only Like and Comments are made available for mobile web apps) and you should use a Fb.login() style approach instead.

Comment: [Here is a link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/mobileweb/) that shows how to use the facebook login button on mobile. Very confused.

Comment: FYI. I changed it to the FB.login & it worked. Go ahead and add an answer & I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mobile web apps, I'd recommend to use FB.login via the SDK itself rather than through the use of the login button. If nothing else it gives you greater programmatic control of the user flow & experience.

The canonical "simplest ever social app" snippet is:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log('Fetching user info');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Hello ' + response.name + '!');
     });
  } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize');
  }
});
```

Also you're including the JS SDK for the plugin anyway, so there's no payload overhead. More details on FB.login here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: App ID: 441079762589798. 
[Screenshot](http://gyazo.com/f9dd03d7b54a155d75777a37accbed2f) showing my settings